# Device for 3D modelling, APIs for "3D pen project"?

Tags: 3d, game-engine, 3d-modelling

I am a hobbyist programmer. My dream of developing my own "Game Engine" always face a road block when it comes to character modelling.

I have no past past background of such thing, though i tried learning those 3D modelling tools (max, maya and alike) but always found myself struggling.

Since i'm awesome at pen and paper i was wondering if there are any hardware devices which could help me in designing models with the ease of pen and paper. And/Or any link for pranab mistary's "3D pen project" related APIs so that i could manage to help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really an answer about hardware, but have a look at ZBrush, it has a slightly different interesting approach to modelling than Max, Maya.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of free modeling tools you can use that don't take the usual box-modeling approach:

1. [Sculptris](http://www.drpetter.se/project_sculpt.html) - ZBrush-like tool, has many useful features
2. [ShapeShop](http://www.shapeshop3d.com/) - draw and extrude/revolve your outlines, very good for organic models (and since you're good at pen/paper, might be a good fit)
3. [hamaPatch and sPatch](http://www.eatonhand.com/images/spatch.htm) - model using splines, which makes complex and subtle surfaces really easy to do

Edit: if you don't already have one, I suggest [getting a tablet](http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=dp_brlad_entry?ie=UTF8&node=16034531#/ref=sr_nr_p_72_0?rh=n:172282,n%3a!493964,n:541966,n:172456,n:172493,n:16034531,p_72:1248879011&bbn=16034531&ie=UTF8&qid=1314464704&rnid=1248877011). All of the above tools will be much more accessible to you if you're not confined to a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are awesome at pen and paper, definitely, you need a tablet (Actually the Wacom are the best [www.wacom.eu](http://www.wacom.eu) ).

As imsky said the best option is a ZBrush-like tool (Mudbox, Zbrush, Sculptris (free but limited in compare)). With this tools you can make quick sketchs which can be exported to other modelling tools like maya, max, etc.

Other option is to buy or download free models from the internet...not always the best solution but useful for props, etc.